# How to change some function to be compatible for iOS 10 or below for some function in my snapchat like camera view controller

Tags: ios, swift, camera

[image]

I am making a view controller to make a camera view controller like snapchat camera. my code below is worked perfectly for iOS 11 or above. to be honest, I don't really grasp my code since i just follow along the tutorial for this snapchat like camera view controller

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import SVProgressHUD
class CameraVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: DesignableButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var retryButton: DesignableButton!

    // to receive data from MainMenuVC
    var employeeData : Employee?
    var checkinData = CheckIn()

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    // which camera input do we want to use
    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?

    // to keep track which camera do we use currently
    var currentDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    var toggleCameraGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
    var zoomInGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
    var zoomOutGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()

    var thereIsAnError : Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if thereIsAnError {
                cameraButton.isHidden = true
                cameraButton.isEnabled = false
                retryButton.isHidden = false
                retryButton.isEnabled = true
            } else {
                cameraButton.isHidden = false
                cameraButton.isEnabled = true
                retryButton.isHidden = true
                retryButton.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getDateTimeFromServer()

        // initial value
        thereIsAnError = false
        timeLabel.text = ""
        dateLabel.text = ""
        cameraButton.isEnabled = false
        cameraButton.alpha = 0.4

        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()
        setGestureRecognizer()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if checkinData.dateTime != nil {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func shutterButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // when the button is pressed, we capture the image and set the photoOutput
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)

        // perform segue is below in the AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate
    }

    @IBAction func retryButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if checkinData.dateTime == nil {
            getDateTimeFromServer()
        }
    }
}

extension CameraVC {

    // MARK: - Helper Methods

    // MARK: - Helper Methods
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToCheckinDetail" {
            let checkinDetailTVC = segue.destination as! CheckinDetailVC
            checkinDetailTVC.dataOfCheckin = checkinData
            checkinDetailTVC.dataOfEmployee = employeeData

            // to set the navbar back button title in the checkinDetailVC
            navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        }
    }

    func  getDateTimeFromServer() {

        SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading Data")

        NetworkingService.getCurrentTimeFromServer { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .failure:
                self.thereIsAnError = true
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                self.showAlert(alertTitle: "Sorry", alertMessage: "Internet connection issue, please tap the retry button.", actionTitle: "Back")
            case .success(let timeFromServer) :
                guard let stringDateTimeServer = timeFromServer as? String else {return}
                self.checkinData.dateTime = stringDateTimeServer

                let dateTimeService = DateTimeService(fromDateTimeString: stringDateTimeServer)
                let time = dateTimeService.parsingDateAndTime()?.timeOnly
                self.timeLabel.text = "\(time ?? "-")"
                self.dateLabel.text = DateTimeService.changeFormat(of: stringDateTimeServer, toFormat: "dd MMM yyyy")


                self.cameraButton.isEnabled = true
                self.cameraButton.alpha = 1
                self.thereIsAnError = false

                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }

    func setGestureRecognizer() {
        // change camera from front to back
        toggleCameraGestureRecognizer.direction = .up
        toggleCameraGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchCamera))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(toggleCameraGestureRecognizer)

        // Zoom In recognizer
        zoomInGestureRecognizer.direction = .right
        zoomInGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(zoomIn))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(zoomInGestureRecognizer)

        // Zoom Out recognizer
        zoomOutGestureRecognizer.direction = .left
        zoomOutGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(zoomOut))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(zoomOutGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func setupCaptureSession() {
        // to specify image resolution and quality we want, we set to the highest resolution possible
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    }

    func setupDevice() {
        // to decide whether we use front or back camer

        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
        let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices

        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
                backCamera = device
            } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
                frontCamera = device
            }
        }
        // default device
        currentDevice = frontCamera
    }

    func setupInputOutput() {
        //  after the camera capture that image (input), we generate the image DATA (output)
        // put the input and output to capture Session

        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentDevice!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func setupPreviewLayer() {
        // to display image data on the screen

        cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
    }

    @objc func switchCamera() {
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()

        // Change the device based on the current camera
        let newDevice = (currentDevice?.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back) ? frontCamera : backCamera

        // Remove all inputs from the session
        for input in captureSession.inputs {
            captureSession.removeInput(input as! AVCaptureDeviceInput)
        }

        // Change to the new input
        let cameraInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput
        do {
            cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newDevice!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if captureSession.canAddInput(cameraInput) {
            captureSession.addInput(cameraInput)
        }

        currentDevice = newDevice
        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    }

    @objc func zoomIn() {
        if let zoomFactor = currentDevice?.videoZoomFactor {
            if zoomFactor < 5.0 {
                let newZoomFactor = min(zoomFactor + 1.0, 5.0)
                do {
                    try currentDevice?.lockForConfiguration()
                    currentDevice?.ramp(toVideoZoomFactor: newZoomFactor, withRate: 1.0)
                    currentDevice?.unlockForConfiguration()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func zoomOut() {
        if let zoomFactor = currentDevice?.videoZoomFactor {
            if zoomFactor > 1.0 {
                let newZoomFactor = max(zoomFactor - 1.0, 1.0)
                do {
                    try currentDevice?.lockForConfiguration()
                    currentDevice?.ramp(toVideoZoomFactor: newZoomFactor, withRate: 1.0)
                    currentDevice?.unlockForConfiguration()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func startRunningCaptureSession() {
        // to start capturing the data
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}

extension CameraVC: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
            checkinData.photo = UIImage(data: imageData)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToCheckinDetail", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

but when I set my deployment target to iOS 10.3, I got an error that said  some method is only available for iOS 11 or newer.

[image]

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
            checkinData.photo = UIImage(data: imageData)
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToCheckinDetail", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

> 1. AVCapturePhoto' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer
> 2. fileDataRepresentation()' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer

and

[image]

```
func setupInputOutput() {
        //  after the camera capture that image (input), we generate the image DATA (output)
        // put the input and output to capture Session

        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentDevice!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

> 'jpeg' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer

Please help me, I need some function that equal to those function for iOS 10 (at least) or below.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an AVCapturePhotoOutput object. Use its properties to determine supported capture settings and to enable certain features (for example, whether to capture Live Photos).

   ```
   fileprivate var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput!
   ```
2. Create and configure an AVCapturePhotoSettings object to choose
   features and settings for a specific capture (for example, whether to enable image stabilization or flash).

   ```
   photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
   if self.session.canAddOutput(photoOutput) {
        self.session.addOutput(photoOutput)
   }
   ```
3. Capture an image by passing your photo settings object to the
   `capturePhoto(with:delegate:)` method along with a delegate object implementing the AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate protocol. The photo capture output then calls your delegate to notify you of significant events during the capture process.

   ```
   queue.async { self.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: AVCapturePhotoSettings(), delegate: self) }
   ```